# How to scrape data from Wall Street Journal Market Diaries with no table id's and or no values in the xmlresponse

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to pull information from https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary.

This is my code

```
Private Function WebDownload() As Boolean
    Dim xml As XMLHTTP
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim searchArray(7) As String
    Dim vRspText As Object
    Dim y, x, z As Integer
    Dim vString, vValue As Object
    Dim aRegArray As Object
    Dim s As String
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim neg As Short
    Dim sMktSum As String
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable '<== Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim htmlobject As HTMLDivElement
    On Error GoTo Error_webDownload_Handler

    html = New HTMLDocument

    'false is default for boolean
    WebDownload = False

    xml = New XMLHTTP
    'sURL = "http://quote.yahoo.com/mo"
    sUrl = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary"
    xml.open("GET", sUrl, False)
    'send the request and returns data
    xml.send()
    'set content to local variable
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object vRspText. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
    'vRspText = xml.responseText
    html.body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

    htmlobject = html.getElementById("root")
    MessageBox.Show(htmlobject)

    x = 1
    x = InStr(x, CStr(vRspText), "issuesTraded")
    If x > 0 Then
        If z = 0 Then
            'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object vRspText. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
            sMktSum = Mid(vRspText, x, 20000)
            'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object RegExpTest(). Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
            sMktSum = RegExpTest("\d+(,?\ d \ d \ d) *\ .*\ d * ", sMktSum)
            sValue = Mid(sMktSum, 1, Len(sMktSum))
            _mvarDowClose = CDbl(sValue)
        End If
    End If
```

When using the inspecting tool, I am able to see the values in the table cells, although when getting the xml.responseText there is no data values in the xml file. My guess is this is because this data is being pulled in on their end from a script.

I attempted to scrape this data through finding the name of the cells with `x = InStr(x, CStr(vRspText), "issuesTraded")` although I am not able to find data values in the xml file.

I also attempted using htmldocuments although I am unable to use an htmlTable because the table that I am trying to getElementById() has no ID value. I have looked into xpath's because of this.

Comment: You will need to automate a browser to do this - once the page has loaded, grab all of the `<table>` elements and examine (eg) the first row of each, looking for the column headers: if you find these then you know that's the table you want.

Answer (score 1):

The data is retrieved dynamically via additional xhr requests for each table which returns json. You can find these in the network tab by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh page. You can then search for values from the table in the xhr list.

You will need a json parser to handle the response. In VBA JSON `{}` is a dictionary that you can loop the `keys` of or access by `key`; [] indicates a collection you can `For Each` over. The json is nested. You will need to familiarize yourself with these concepts. I will show you how to parse the json and recreate the table, via an array, and then to write out to sheet. I will do this for the first table.

For json parsing  I use [`jsonconverter.bas`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas), Download raw code from there and add to standard module called JsonConverter. You then need to go `VBE > Tools > References > Add reference` to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code (this is for if you import the .bas direct).

Examine the json structures for the different tables and then determine how best to re-write your code so you can re-use sections of code as functions/subs for each xhr request.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMarketsDiary()
    Dim http As Object, ws As Worksheet, json As Object

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary?id={""application"":""WSJ"",""marketsDiaryType"":""diaries""}&type=mdc_marketsdiary", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'mitigate for being served cached results
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

    Dim instrumentSets As Object, singleSet As Object, header As Object
    Dim instrument As Object, r As Long, c As Long, key As Variant, results()

    Set instrumentSets = json("data")("instrumentSets") 'list of 4 needs converting to tables

    ReDim results(1 To instrumentSets.item(1)("instruments").Count * instrumentSets.Count + 1, 1 To instrumentSets.item(1)("headerFields").Count)

    For Each singleSet In instrumentSets
        c = 1: r = r + 1
        For Each header In singleSet("headerFields")
            results(r, c) = header("label")
            c = c + 1
        Next

        For Each instrument In singleSet("instruments")
            c = 1: r = r + 1
            For Each key In instrument
                If key <> "id" Then
                    results(r, c) = instrument(key)
                    c = c + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```